# Android- bottom Navigation bar is long

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

bottom Navigation bar is long seems like a space is excreted, i tried to solve this problem a days.
This is the problem
: [image]

This is the xml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".Home_activity">

<!-- 813dp -->

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:name="com.anonymous.nr_chemistryteam.BlankFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />


<com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
    android:id="@+id/bottomAppBar"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomAppBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
    android:theme="@style/AppThemeMaterial2"
    app:fabCradleMargin="8dp"
    app:fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius="50dp"
    app:fabCradleVerticalOffset="6dp">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/homeNvBottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/empty_background"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu" />
</com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:backgroundTint="#ff5e00"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_cart"
    app:fabCustomSize="72dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/bottomAppBar"
    app:maxImageSize="34dp" />
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This is the menu xml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="@+id/home_page2"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_home2"
    android:title="Home" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/message_page2"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_message1"
    android:title="Message" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/placeholder"
    android:checkable="false"
    android:title="" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/help_page2"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_help"
    android:title="Help" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/settings_page2"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings"
    android:title="Settings" />
```

I am using coordinator layout so i think coordinator layout is the problem or might be the fragment i used.
what should i do to remove this space (space below bottom Navigation bar that already in picture)?

Comment: Check this android:background="@drawable/empty_background" and this too android:theme="@style/AppThemeMaterial2

Comment: I just checked but it dosen't effect on it

Comment: Can you include those code!?

Comment: copy homeactivity xml code and paste it in new layout

Answer (score 0):

You could try making the height of the Bottom Bar 100dp.